# Python running game.exe from script.py with os

Tags: python

I am working on a program that stores the exe paths for games you have installed on your machine. I am trying to create a button with tkitner which will run the game from this program.

```
import subprocess

game_path = r"D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps\common\RE3\re3.exe"

p = subprocess.Popen(game_path)
```

I've also tried:

```
import os

os.system(game_path)
```

and

```
os.startfile(game_path)
```

each time the program exits and a logger  .txt file is created. Sometimes this .txt file contains the errors which occor, such as

- LoadImage() - Failed to load image: data/ui_gfx/<.png>
  or
- Unable to open csv files: data/translations/common.csv

I've attempted executing from a windowsshortcut rather than the exe itself but I get this error:
[image]

Comment: Some apps insist on being launched in a specific directory.  If you right-click on the desktop icon and view the properties, you can see the starting directory.  You can then do `os.chdir` in your code to put yourself in the same spot.

Comment: Yeah nice, tried the os.chdir method and it has worked. Thanks mate.